# Character pending commands in mappable mode

Tags: vim

If `imap ab c`, then I want that keystrokes `rab` would change char under the cursor to `c`, as it does in *replace mode* (`R`).

Same with other char-pending commands like `t` or `f`.

How can I do it?

Comment: No, the char-pending is not a mappable mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help r` explains how to do this:

> {char} can be entered as a digraph.
>     :lmap mappings apply to {char}.  The CTRL-^ command
>     in Insert mode can be used to switch this on/off.

So, one way is via *digraphs*:

```
:digraph ab 99
```

Or via `:lmap`, but then you have to enable language mappings via `<C-^>` first.

```
:lnoremap ab c
```